# Why does the angular material design disappear when I add a custom angular class to a button?

Tags: css, angular, responsive-design, angular-material

I am trying to add a custom css class directive to my button, but whenever I do that, the angular material design goes away and the button goes back to its default ugly state. How can I make sure that my custom css class gets added to the button without it removing the mat-buutton effects?

> ```
> <button 
>   mat-button
>   [class]="todoItems.completed ? 'delete': null"
>   (click)="deleteTodo(todoItems._id)" 
>   [disabled]="!todoItems.completed">
>           <mat-icon >delete</mat-icon>
> </button>
> ```

Here is the css

```
.delete:hover {
   color: red
}
```

I want my class to be applied only if the completed property is true and when that property is true the delete button will turn red when I hover on it.
The hovering part works fine but the problem I have is that the material design disappears and it turns into the default style of button

Comment: We can't guess what it is just with the HTML. Please, paste the CSS code and a snippet if its possible

Comment: Did you try to add your class with `ngClass`? https://angular.io/api/common/NgClass

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`mat-button` applies its own css classes to the `<button>` at run time.

When you are doing `[class]="todoItems.completed ? 'delete': null"` it is hard overridding these classes.

To append your class to the existing ones, you need to use `ngClass` instead.

Comment: Thank you for letting me know the solution. Turns out I just needed to change the [class] to [ngClass]